# Phone number validation using JavaScript with .NET?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation

How do I validate phone numbers using JavaScript in ASP.NET?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Validating telephone numbers is a difficult problem.

Essentially, you define a regular expression that match the pattern(s) for a valid phone number. The conventions for a phone number are highly local-specific and without knowing something about the users' location, it's hard to generalize. My general rule is "Take what the user gives you, strip off everything but the digits and store only that, formatting it for display. Even that doesn't always work well, because somebody might give you a perfectly valid number like `555-1234 x345`, because they can only be reached via a PBX extension. They've omitted the area code and if you strip off the non-digits, you're left with 5551234345 which would get formatted as 555-123-4335. Not so useful.

- NANP ([North American Numbering Plan](http://www.nanpa.com/)) phone numbers have a 3-digit area code (optional), a 3-digit Central Office (CO/exchange) number and a 4-digit subscriber number, plus optional country code, access code, etc. Conventionally written as (variously, and omitting the country code and access code): (AAA) BBB-CCCC, AAA-BBB-CCCC, AAA.BBB.CCCC, etc. More formally, an NANP number (Zone 1, including the USA and its overseas territories, Candada and most Caribbean countries) should be written as +1:AAA-BBB-CCCC.
- The [French Numbering Plan](http://www.arcep.fr/) currently has 10 digit telephone numbers, written as  xx.xx.xx.xx.xx. It used to have 8-digit numbers, with Isle de France (metro Paris) having special rules. More formally, a French number should be written as +33:xx.xx.xx.xx.xx, except that if dialed form outside France, the leading '0' in the telephone number should be omitted, so from an outside perspective, the phone number should be expressed as +33:x.xx.xx.xx.xx.

Other countries and dialing/numbering plans have their own rules. Sometimes there are special rules in places regarding calls placed to and from specific locations in a given country (e.g., it used to be that calling a number located outside Isle de France from Paris required dialing a '16' prefix first.) Here in the US, some locations, require dialing all 10 digits even for local calls.

More info (and links) at the [World Telephone Numbering Guide](http://www.wtng.info/)

Answer (score 0):

```
function validatePhoneNumber(elementValue){  
    var phoneNumberPattern = /^\(?(\d{3})\)?[- ]?(\d{3})[- ]?(\d{4})$/;  
    return phoneNumberPattern.test(elementValue);  
}
```

Use it like this:

```
if (validatePhoneNumber('123-456-7890'))
{
    // do something
}
```